# Error in 1:nrow(newdata) : argument of length 0 while using SVM predict

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, predict, rscript

I'm trying to predict A values based upon model trained by svm. 
This is how my train and test data looks like:

```
A     B    C     D
r00  r01  r02   r03
...  ...  ...   ...
```

Code Snippet is given below:

> featvecs = ["B"]

```
for (f in 1:nrow(featvecs)) {
    tuned <- svm(A ~., data = train[,c("A",featvecs[f,])], gamma = 0.01, cost = 10, kernel= "radial")
    svm.predict <- predict(tuned, test[,featvecs[f,]])
}
```

I'm getting the following error for the svm.predict line and am not really sure why?

```
Error in 1:nrow(newdata) : argument of length 0
```

Structure for train data:

```
structure(list(A = structure(6L, .Label = c("'1'", 
"'2'", "'3'" ), class = "factor"), B =  structure(15L, .Label = c(...)...)
```

Structure for test data:

```
structure(list(A = structure(2L, .Label = c("'1'", 
"'2'", "'3'" ), class = "factor"), B =  structure(17L, .Label = c(...)...)
```

Comment: It is useful if you can provide a small example of the whole process you are going through - especially a small subset of your data `dput(head(train))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `featvecs` has only one column, so `featvecs[f,]` is of length `1`.

Then `test[,featvecs[f,]]` outputs a vector instead of the expected data.frame (See the difference between `mtcars[, "mpg"]` and `mtcars[, "mpg", drop = FALSE]`), and `nrow()` applied to a vector outputs `NULL`: `1:nrow(newdata)` in the source code of `svm.predict()` gives `1:NULL` that causes your error.

Try adding `drop = FALSE` to `test[,featvecs[f,], drop = FALSE]` so that you get a data.frame.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Worked like a charm.